# Euclid's Proof of Pythagorean Theorem. Can you explain this one step?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

[image]How is half of square CFEG, that is triangle FGC is equal to triangle FCD?

I was explained that it's because the base of the triangles are the same, that is CF.

But they don't have the same height?[image: Euclid's proof] 
HOW?

edit: 
I made DGE collinear.

Still doesn't make sense to me.
How is GC the height of triangle GCB?

Comment: They *do* have the same height.  DGC is a right angle.  So DG is parallel to CF.  They have the same base CF and the same height CG.

Comment: Your drawing doesn't make it look like DGE are colinear.  If you drew it cleaner and viewed oriented the picture so that CF and DGE appeared horizontal you'd see that triangle CFG and CFD have the same height (although CFG is stretched waaaaaaay out).

Comment: The triangle GCB does not have the height drawn in.  GCB is congruent to FCD by Side Angle Side.  So GCB =DCF because they are congruent.  DCF eGCF because they both have the same base and height.  If we viewed GCB on its side it would have a height that is equal to F BUT it simply isn't drawn in because we don'don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

They actually do have the same height, if the height is measured as the altitude on $\overline{CF}$.  The reason why you're not seeing it is because the drawing is inaccurate:  in fact, points $D$, $G$, and $E$ are collinear if $\angle DGC$ is a right angle.  Since $D$, $G$, $E$ all lie on a common line, and this line is parallel to $\overline{CF}$, as the opposite sides of a square are parallel, it immediately follows that $$|\triangle DCF| = |\triangle GCF|,$$ since they share the same base $CF$, and the height is equal to the length of $GC$.

Comment: IT DOESN'T MAKE SENSE TO ME. FOR TRIANGLE GCB, THE BASE IS GC, THE HEIGHT IS ALSO GC? THAT'S INSANE

Comment: Don't yell.  GCF and DCF both have base CF and altitude CG. Why are you yelling about GCB.  Hero pup never mentioned GCB

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to yell... Definitely wasn't yelling. I just find it ridiculous that I'm so far lost to understanding the altitude/height. I get all the steps except for this one.

Comment: Thank you though. I think im getting to it

Answer (score 1):

In that drawing, you'd never think that $DGE$ was a line!

$DCF$ and $GCF$ have the same base and same height as $DG$ is parallel to
$CF$.